# How to inherit a static property with a unique value for each subclass?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a series of objects, lets call them buildings, that each share certain properties that are static for that building, but different for each building, such as price.  I assumed that the best way to implement this was to create an abstract superclass with the shared price attribute and set the values in each subclass, but I cannot figure out how to get this to work.  Here is an example of something I have tried:

```
using System;
public abstract class Buildings
{
   internal static int price;
   internal static int turnsToMake;
}
```

```
using System;
public class Walls : Buildings
{
    public Walls()
    {
        price = 200;
        turnsToMake = 5;
    }
}
```

This works fine for construction, but if I want to check the price before creating it (to check if the player has enough money) then it just returns a null value.  I'm sure that it is is a super simple fix, but I can't figure it out.  Any help?

Comment: Since we are talking about subclassing here, can you show us how you create instances of `Buildings` (or of a derived class) depending on `price` and `turnsToMake`? Do you have some kind of factory class or method?

Comment: May I ask why you care so much about creating the object? It's just an object. Nothing wrong with creating a building object, verify if the player can afford it, if not, leave the building for the GC.

Comment: Sadly C# doesn't support class properties/methods, so it's not possible to write code like this.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Static properties *are* class properties, so C# supports these. What it doesn't support are *virtual* class properties. And that concept perhaps doesn't make much sense anyway, since static members are resolved at compile-time, while `virtual` methods are all about making polymorphism work, at run-time.

Comment: @stakx Class methods in the way delphi used them receive the type they're called on as first argument. They can be virtual, but even if they're not, receiving the class can be useful. Virtual class methods/properties would be a great solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Interesting! I'll have to take a look at Delphi's class  properties/methods then. Thx for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to check the price before creating it […]*

I suppose that's how you got to static fields; however, static and virtual behaviour cannot be combined. That is, you would have to re-declare your static fields for each subclass. Otherwise, all your subclasses share the exact same fields and overwrite each others' values.

Another solution would be to use the [**`Lazy<T, TMetadata>`** type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986615.aspx) from the .NET (4 or higher) framework class library:

```
public class Cost
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int TurnsToMake { get; set; }
}

var lazyBuildings = new Lazy<Buildings, Cost>(
        valueFactory: () => new Walls(),
        metadata: new Cost { Price = 200, TurnsToMake = 5 });

if (lazyBuildings.Metadata.Price < …)
{
    var buildings = lazyBuildings.Value;
}
```

That is, the metadata (`.Metadata`) now resides outside of the actual types (`Buildings`, `Walls`) and can be used to decide whether you actually want to build an instance ( `.Value`) of it.

(Thanks to polymorphism, you can have a whole collection of such "lazy factories" and find a building type to instantiate based on the metadata of each factory.)

Comment: Could you please provide a full example? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There is a "patchy" yet simple solution that's worth to consider. If you define your base class as a Generic class, and in deriving classes set T as the class itself, It will work.

This happens because .NET statically defines a new type for each new  definition.

For example:

```
class Base<T>
{
    public static int Counter { get; set; }

    public Base()
    {
    }
}

class DerivedA : Base<DerivedA>
{
    public DerivedA()
    {
    }
}

class DerivedB : Base<DerivedB>
{
    public DerivedB()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DerivedA.Counter = 4;
        DerivedB.Counter = 7;

        Console.WriteLine(DerivedA.Counter.ToString()); // Prints 4
        Console.WriteLine(DerivedB.Counter.ToString()); // Prints 7

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution for some reason

Comment: Very, very nice solution to a tricky problem. Well explained too. Much appreciated. Hats off to you, sir.

Comment: This is great when you call the property on the derived class, but what if you need to have a shared static method on the base class that uses the static property value from the derived class?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `static`.  Static says that all instances of Building have the same value.  A derived class will not inherit its own copy of the statics; but would always modify the base class statics.  In your design there would only be one value for price and turnsToMake.

This should work for you:

```
public abstract class Buildings
{
  internal int price;
  internal int turnsToMake;
}
```

However, most people don't like using fields these days and prefer properties.

```
public abstract class Buildings
{
  internal int Price { get; set; }
  internal int TurnsToMake { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's excatly what I would do. +1

Comment: If I understood the OP correctly, there is still the problem that you'd have to instantiate `Buildings` before you can read the values of these properties. The only solution is to extract the property values into a separate "metadata" object that is associated with a specific class; something like `KeyValuePair<Cost, Func<Buildings>>`.

Comment: @stakx You are correct that that is still my issue.  Is there not some simpler way to do this?

Comment: @Garrett: I dare say no. To inspect an object before it is created is impossible. Therefore my suggestion to inspect a diffeent object than the one you're (perhaps) going to create. You could look into custom attributes (`[Cost(Price=10,TurnsToMake=2)] class X`), or into the metadata suggestions made above and in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Uri Abramson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176547/uri-abramson)'s answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222118/15740725):

If you need to access the static property from within the Base class, use reflection to get the value from `T`. Also, you can enforce that `Base` must be inherited using `T` of the derived type.

e.g.

```
class Base<T> where T : Base <T> {
        static int GetPropertyValueFromDerivedClass<PropertyType>(BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
        {
            return typeof(T).GetProperty(PropertyName, Flags)?.GetValue(null);
        }

        static int Counter{ get => GetPropertyValueFromDerivedClass(); }
}
     
        static int DoubleCounter{ return Counter*2; } //returns 8 for DerivedA and 14 for DerivedB
}
```

If you have a better way to do this, please post.

Answer (score 0):

Not as easy for the inheritor, but workable...

```cs
public abstract class BaseType
{
    public abstract contentType Data { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedType : BaseType
{
    protected static contentType _inheritedTypeContent;
    public override contentType Data { get => _inheritedTypeContent; set => _inheritedTypeContent = value; }
}
```